# Fiori Controller.js Changes not Reflecting without Modifying Component-Preload.js

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a Fiori app that I need to customize in VS Code. The change is to be made in the Detail.controller.js file. I noticed that the changes I made in the Detail.controller.js file did not reflect until I made those exact changes in the Component-preload.js file.

Interestingly, I haven't encountered a similar situation with View files. Can someone shed light on why this behavior seems specific to Controller files? Does this imply that for code changes in Controller files, updating only the Component-preload.js file is necessary?

TIA,
Ruzna

Comment: How did you generate or get your component-preload in first place? As in local development you shouldn't really have a component-preload, it's mostly used for production environments

Comment: It got created when I migrated the app to my FLP server via Fiori Tools extensions in VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be cache issue. If you are deploying your application to SAP system after developments on VSCode then you can try below tcodes and programs to clean your cache. Then, hopefully, you can see latest developments. Also don't forget to try incognito mode on your browser.

T-Code:

- /n/IWFND/CACHE_CLEANUP in gateway system
- /n/IWBEP/CACHE_CLEANUP in
  backend system

Programs:

- /UI2/DELETE_CACHE_AFTER_IMP
- /UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE(run this one only for your app)
- /UI2/INVALIDATE_CLIENT_CACHES
- /UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to check this by clearing cache in VSCode and test the changes live using npm run start before deploying it to the server? My Fiori App is linked to a test server. I used the Fiori Tools Extensions to migrate my app before connecting it to the service url.

Comment: Not sure, I didn't use Fiori tools extension. Maybe you can try to delete component-preload.js and 'if possible' re-build your app. It should regenerate component-preload.js with your latest developments.